# Selenium Not Able to Find Elements By ClassName

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

```
<table class="sc-fAEnHe ePMtc">
<tbody>
<tr class="sc-fAEnHe ePMtc">
<td classs"sc-jEECVv IBUtl">
</td>
</tr>
```

**When I use Selenium's Find element by class it is able to find the element, I even tried replacing space (after e and r or v and I) with ".", "-" and "_" but it did not worked.
I Used The Code Below**

```
try:
    match_history_table = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-fAEnHe ePMtc'))
    )
except Exception:
    print("Error Finding Match History Table")
    driver.quit()
```

**It always returned the Exception (EC is selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)**
***>Note: Find Elements By Tag is not an Option For me***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doc from `By.CLASS_NAME` found in selenium-java-bindings.

> Find elements based on the value of the "class" attribute. Only one class name should be used. If an element has multiple classes, please use cssSelector(String).

Try with `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.sc-fAEnHe.ePMtc')`:

```
try:
    match_history_table = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.sc-fAEnHe.ePMtc'))
    )
except Exception:
    print("Error Finding Match History Table")
    driver.quit()
```

---

**Referenses**

- json wire protocol
  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/legacy/json_wire_protocol/#sessionsessionidelement

> *class name*  Returns an element whose class name contains the search value; compound class names are not permitted.

- W3C webdriver

  And *class_name* not mentioned in W3C protocol, so it might become legacy
  https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#locator-strategies

Comment: Error Finding Match History Table, I have tried replacing the " space " with "."

Comment: @Snehasisbasu does this error appeared using `BY.CSS_SELECTOR` ? I've tested this approach on other site for multiple classes and it worked.

Comment: I know thats why I am confused why it is not working>>Update: I have found in the web code there are two table with the same tag name but selenium is only able to find one table (not the required one) even though both the table are present in the code.

Comment: @Snehasisbasu if those tables contain the same classes, try `EC.presence_of_all_elements_located` instead of `EC.presence_of_element_located`. This will return a list and you'll be able to get element by index.

Comment: Also, I've created the page with your source code example locally and checked if css selector works. So, I was able to find the element by `'.sc-fAEnHe.ePMtc'`.

Comment: I think its something with the web page only, so what is happing is until a certain line of code selenium is able to detect the elements but inside (after) that line of code it just now detecting a single element. Do you want the a page link where this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

1. when you search for class name value, notice that "sc-fAEnHe ePMtc" represent 2 class names separated by space, so you can search by "sc-fAEnHe" or by "ePMtc"
2. besides that make sure that presence_of_element_located doesn't require an element with height and width that greater then 0

Comment: Actually I think the problem is with the web page, what is happening is after a certain line of code selenium not detecting a single element.